# Android: Get all sent sms? (outbox)

Tags: android, get, sms, inbox

I'm writing an app to backup all text messages. Been working on it for a while and i just realized the method i'm using to retrieve sms' only gets the ones i got (the inbox).

Is it possible, in any way, to get the outbox?

If it's not in the Android API, is it possible to get it from the default SMS app somehow? Even if not everybody uses it it will work for now, it's kind of urgent.

Comment: how to read sent items failed messages

Answer (score 12, accepted):

to get the sent messages you need to read `sent-directory`

Use this Uri query

```
Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
```

Comment: Thank you, i will give it a shot in 3 minutes.

Comment: I got it working. Since i need both the inbox and outbox i just did "content://sms" and i got both, however, it took me 10 times a long to do. I have received more sms than i have sent, why do does it take so much longer?

Comment: How to get sent message which is in pending state?